# Mysql - Get season from current month

Tags: mysql

I have the following table of seasons:

```
| id  | name   | start_month | end_month |
------------------------------------------
| 101 | Summer | 12          | 2         |
| 102 | Winter | 6           | 8         |
| 103 | Spring | 9           | 11        |
| 104 | Fall   | 3           | 5         |
```

I need to get the season by month. Say current month is 2 (February), I want Summer to be the output.

I can get other seasons to work by simply having the where condition `start_month >= 4 and end_month <= 4`. But this won't work with Summer since the season crosses into next year.

What do I have to do to handle the case of Summer?

One solution I thought was to use dates instead of month number like `1980-12-01` and use `between` function but it gets a bit complicated for the user end.

It'd be great if it could work with just month numbers.

Comment: As I can see, it is not dependent on year. You can extract month from the date and compare.

Comment: Are you talking about the second solution using dates?

Comment: February is easy. January is a more interesting problem.

Comment: The solution should be same for both and even works for other seasons as well. You can't say `current month = end month` so its solved. February is just an example.

Comment: Arguably simpler to have a seaons table containing 12 months

Comment: That's not simple for the user. This info is shown to admins of the site and they can make all changes. Even add more if they want, selecting the start and end month.

Comment: How did you generate this non standard month sequence number?

Comment: What do you mean "non-standard"?

Comment: Wait...are you in the Southern hemisphere?

Comment: Welcome to Australia! But like I said, it could be anything, its user editable. I need a solution to the case when the season crosses through the end of the year. You might as well call it winter, programmatically it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's going to get a bit complicated for the end user whichever solution you go with - consider making a function available.

Comment: Handle it with code instead of Mysql query?

Comment: What code you only have mysql tagged?

Comment: The website is on php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
(month(d) between start_month and end_month) or 
      (start_month>end_month and (month(d)>=start_month or month(d)<=end_month))
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Ys8XDftYCpNqYeMWYgqov/1)

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, either inside the two months or outside them both.